# Prove that $4((p-1)!+1)\equiv -p\mod{(p(p+2)})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have found this interesting theorem but with no proof:

"$p$ and $p+2$ are twin primes iff $4((p-1)!+1)\equiv -p\mod{(p(p+2)})$"

I have tried to prove it with classical N.T. theorems but I just get nowhere. Any advise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem: prove separately modulo $p$ and $p+2$.

Comment: do you mean "iff" instead of "iif"? if yes, which of the two directions have you been able to prove?

Comment: [wilson's theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiplrfFB6h0&t=4s) may also help.

Comment: To apply Wilson's Theorem for $p+2$ try multiplying through by $p$ (these are coprime if $p$ is odd).

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408018.pdf

Comment: @supinf Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: @user328442 Also here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02836740

Comment: Thank you @LordSharktheUnknown, Mark Bennet and Roddy Macphee